# How to customize the serializer data of an onetomany relationship in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I define the serializer for the image model and call it up to the postserializer to give data at once when the postserializer is called. There is no problem with the operation, but I don't give json data as I want.

Now I give it to you like this is it.

```
{
        "pk": 0,
        "author": {
            "id": 0,
            "email": "",
            "username": "",
            "profile": "url",
            "following": 0,
            "followers": 0
        },
        "title": "",
        "text": "",
        "view": 0,
        "images": [
            {
                "image": "url"
            },
            {
                "image": "url"
            },
            {
                "image": "url"
            },
            {
                "image": "url"
            }
        ],
        "like_count": 0,
        "comment_count": 0,
        "liker": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "tag": null,
        "created_at": "2020-10-06T21:46:48.039354+09:00"
    },
```

I want this.

```
{
            "pk": 0,
            "author": {
                "id": 0,
                "email": "",
                "username": "",
                "profile": "url",
                "following": 0,
                "followers": 0
            },
            "title": "",
            "text": "",
            "view": 0,
            "images": [
                url,
                url,
                url,
                url
            ],
            "like_count": 0,
            "comment_count": 0,
            "liker": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "tag": null,
            "created_at": "2020-10-06T21:46:48.039354+09:00"
        },
```

How will json come out the way I want? Here is my code.

serializers.py

```
class ImageSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    image = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True)

    class Meta :
        model = Image
        fields = ('image', )

class CommentSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    comments_author = userProfileSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta :
        model = Comment
        fields = ('pk', 'comments_author', 'text', 'created_at')

    def create (self, validated_data) :
        return Comment.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def validate (self, attrs) :
        text = attrs.get('text', '')

        error = {}

        if text is None :
            error['message'] = '본문은 빈칸일 수 없습니다.'
            raise serializers.ValidationError(error)

        return attrs

class LikeSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer) :

    class Meta :
        model = Like
        fields = '__all__'

class LikerSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    id = serializers.IntegerField(source='liker.pk')

    class Meta :
        model = Like
        fields = ('id', )

class PostSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    author = userProfileSerializer(read_only=True)
    like_count = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    comment_count = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    images = ImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    liker = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta :
        model = Post
        fields = ('pk', 'author', 'title', 'text', 'view', 'images', 'like_count', 'comment_count', 'liker', 'tag', 'created_at')

    def create (self, validated_data) :
        images_data = self.context['request'].FILES
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for image_data in images_data.getlist('image') :
            Image.objects.create(post=post, image=image_data)

        return post

    def validate (self, attrs) :
        title = attrs.get('title', '')
        text = attrs.get('text', '')

        error = {}

        if title is None and text is None :
            error['message'] = '제목과 본문은 빈칸일 수 없습니다.'
            raise serializers.ValidationError(error)

        if title is None :
            error['message'] = '제목은 빈칸일 수 없습니다.'
            raise serializer.ValidationError(error)

        if text is None :
            error['message'] = '본문은 빈칸일 수 없습니다.'    
            raise serializer.ValidationError(error)

        return attrs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`SlugRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) instead of `ImageSerializer` in your `PostSerializer`:

```py
class PostSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
  ...
  images = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field='image')
```

Comment: I tried it but it makes error 'Image' object has no attribute 'url'

Comment: My answer was edited, `slug_field` should be 'image'